# How to perform double click on a repeater row?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="table">
   <div class="header">
      <div class="w10r">Id</div>
      <div class="w20r">Title</div>
   </div>
   <div ng-repeat="row in home.grid.view">
      <div>{{ row.id }}</div>
      <div>{{ row.title }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to double click on the first row in the repeater and below is my test code.

```
element.all(by.repeater('row in home.grid.view')).first()
       .then(function (element) {
            browser.actions().doubleClick(element).perform();
});
```

When I execute the test code, the cursor would click on the table header instead of on the first row of the repeater. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems you haven't mentioned anywhere to click first row of repeater. You might have to use some extra ID for particular div you want to click and pass it on to function.

```
<div ng-repeat="row in home.grid.view">
  <div ng-repeat="Some Id">{{ row.id }}</div>
  <div>{{ row.title }}</div>
</div>
```

And modify your code to click that particular row with div ID:

```
element.all(by.repeater('Some ID')).first()
   .then(function (element) {
        browser.actions().doubleClick(element).perform();
});
```

Hope this helps!